# How to rewrite, redirect and change some parts of URL with Nginx and Perl Module

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, perl-module, lowercase, permanent

I'm trying to do a redirect in Nginx with Perl module configured.

I need to do some changes for one URL:

http://example-domain.org/es/Madrid/511/Delicias --> http://example-domain.org/es/restaurants-madrid/delicias

1. I need change an uppercase URL to lowercase URL
2. Change URL structure like the example

Somebody can help me to do this type of rewrite rule in nginx?

Comment: You want to redirect from furst to second? How many such urls do you have?

Comment: From first to second, that's it! I have hundreds of urls like that... That's the problem. I need do lowercase and change url structure at the same time like in example...

Comment: Are the uppercase urls handled by perl? If so then you could convert to lower case and send a redirect in perl.

Comment: Yes, I transform to lowercase by a function in perl locate in nginx.conf but I need to transform the URL like the example too... I cannot do two rewrites (one to lowercas and two for transform the Url) because server goes to a infinite redirecting loop... I need some way to do both actions. I know how to do in htaccess of Apache but not in virtualhost with nginx...